# How to register nameserver for my server?

Tags: web-services, web, webserver, client-server, nameservers

Well, recently I installed a Apache server at home and currently it is linked with Internet via IP address. Now I have decided to start a hosting service but yet not my server have name server like ns1.domain.com or ns2.domain.com. My Question is that "Where I can register server name", for free?

Comment: Google is thy friend!

Answer (score 0):

Add A records for ns1 and ns2 that point to your server's DNS provider.

You will need to have a DNS server setup somewhere.